# CREATE TABLE Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$con->query("CREATE TABLE jobs
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title VARCHAR(32),
Company VARCHAR(32),
Country VARCHAR(32),
City VARCHAR(32),
Email VARCHAR(32),
Website VARCHAR(32),
Description VARCHAR(1000)
);");
```

Does anyone know why it does not work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I dont get any errors either

Comment: Maybe you don't have error reporting turned on? Maybe you don't have the proper error reporting level set? Maybe you show us some more code? Maybe you create some indexes on your columns for fast querying?

Comment: mysql ? varchar max is 255

Comment: Suggestions: 1. At the top of your PHP use `error_reporting('E_ALL')` during development. 2. Make sure you selected the Database before executing this query.

Comment: @Dagon Wrong (at least for MySQL versions >= 5.0.3) - [read the fourth paragraph](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).

Comment: @Marcel well i'm a little out of date, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only define a column as `AUTO_INCREMENT` if it is a `PRIMARY KEY`.

So, simply add a `PRIMARY KEY` to the `AUTO INCREMENT` column, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title VARCHAR(32),
Company VARCHAR(32),
Country VARCHAR(32),
City VARCHAR(32),
Email VARCHAR(32),
Website VARCHAR(32),
Description VARCHAR(1000),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Great, worked! Marking as best answer

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain the downvote / suggest an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

```
Because there was no primary key defined,try this

CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(32),
    Company VARCHAR(32),
    Country VARCHAR(32),
    City VARCHAR(32),
    Email VARCHAR(32),
    Website VARCHAR(32),
    Description VARCHAR(1000)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Incorrect table definition; 
there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Add pripary key to ID

```
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I dont get any errors either

While you **should**.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Having this line in your code, you will know the problem immediately,  and solve it without wasting the power of community.